# How do i send Delete request using Volley with Json object as a parameter?

Tags: java, android, json

My put method is working fine, but just changing the put request to Delete then its not working,, I tried even by sending its header. but still not working. I even tried Json object to set the parameter. Thanks in advance.

```html
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.DELETE, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("blalala", response);
                String qtyReserved1 = response.toString();
                   Toast.makeText(mContext, "ok" + qtyReserved1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "not ok" + username + Integer.toString(inventoryId), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("screen_name", username);
                params.put("inventory_id", Integer.toString(inventoryId));
                params.put("pending", "true");
                return params;
            }
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json";
            }
        };
        MySingleton.mySingletonInstance(mContext.getApplicationContext()).addToRequestque(stringRequest);
```

Comment: "its not working " . What do you mean. Are you getting any error? or your server not getting your request?

Comment: Server is not getting the request, i guess

Comment: Which is your server. Is it PHP, .Net or Java

Comment: its php server.. is there any mistake in my code,, really appreciate

Comment: try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402229/why-does-my-web-server-software-disallow-put-and-delete-requests?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: put, get and post request work perfectly,, but delete request is troubling me, i wonder others also have hard time on this delete request? im using volley library,

Comment: Is my code correct, pls tell me if i have

Comment: actually this may be a server issue. not sure.. have you tested on postman..is it giving you any response? or error  403? just test this API with postman. if there is no response then it will be a server error

Comment: i have already tested in postman. it works

Comment: is the responce comming in onErrorResponse().? if it so, please provide error.printStackTrace(); and error.networkResponse.statusCode;

Comment: It showing com.android.volley.ServerError Also BasicNetwork.performRequest : Unexpected response code 400 for  http://192.168.4.31/api/canteen/cart

Comment: Its a bad request. problem is from your side. In postman you will find a tab called "code". select it and find the code for java. then try to add that in your project or post here. If you post here, then  I will write volley request for you

Comment: OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\n\t\"screen_name\": \"mariyam.shimaanath\", \n\t\"inventory_id\" : \"19\",\n\t\"pending\" : \"true\"\n}");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("http://192.168.4.31/api/canteen/cart")
  .delete(body)
  .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .addHeader("postman-token", "397cd246-7ec7-582f-bb72-f49f16272a79")
  .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

Comment: How do i post screenshot,, ?

Comment: I found the problem. Actually volley don't send body if you using DELETE. thats why its not working. there is a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803766/volley-how-to-send-delete-request-parameters?answertab=votes#tab-top        .. If this not work try to do this using other library like retrofit, loopj or OkHttp

Comment: Thanks for your time and help , Bless you

Comment: cant i do this using volley library with less code.. I hate to write whole lot of code just do one task,, i only need delete.

Comment: In that case try my answer below. Using loopj is easier than volley.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research, thank God I'm managed to solve the problem,, Not exactly solved the problem had in Delete request in Volley. But, I had to changed the method i need to request from server side. I changed the request to post method, I know it might not be good practice and solution, but now i managed to delete from sever. thats what i need.

Answer (score 0):

Volley library don't send body when you using DELETE method. You can try other library. I am providing you an example by using loopj library

Add dependency in your gradle

```
 compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

Request your web Api

```
  RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
    requestParams.put("screen_name", "mariyam.shimaanath");
    requestParams.put("inventory_id", 19);
    requestParams.put("pending", true);

    String url="192.168.4.31/api/canteen/cart";

    new AsyncHttpClient().delete(url, requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
          String rs = new String(responseBody);

           // do whatever you want

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Bro, onFailure Throwable error message says that its BAD REQUEST

Comment: on log,, E/EGL_emulation: tid 16688: eglSurfaceAttrib(1199): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)